# Não troca de jogador

Tags: javascript, html

No meu programa o jogador mantem-se sempre no "jogador 1". Alguém sabe o porquê?

```
<span id="info_jogador" style="visibility: hidden">Jogador: <span id="jogador">1</span></span>

//script

if (jogador == 1)
{

   document.getElementById("b" + pos + "-" + coluna).src = img_blue;            
   jogador = 2;
   name = img_blue;
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("b" + pos + "-" + coluna).src = img_red;            
    jogador = 1;
    name = img_red;
}
```

Comment: Vc já deu um console.log() nesse 'jogador'? Verificou o tipo?

Comment: @ViníciusMatos veirifcar o tipo não, nem percebi bem o que quiseste dizer. Mas já dei console.log("ola") por exemplo, e o programa está a chegar aquela parte, se me fiz perceber.

Comment: O que é esse `jogador 1` que você mencionou? É a variável jogador? É algum elemento do DOM com o HTML interno "jogador"? Pelo seu código não dá para dizer qual o problema, tente descrever mais o que está acontecendo.

Comment: @user140828 jogador é como se fosse uma "label", o que varia é somente o 1 e o 2. Mas neste momento o programa mantém se somente no 1

Answer (score 1):

Ok, "Jogador" se refere ao HTML, mas não há nenhuma manipulação no DOM para que o valor exibido ao usuário seja alterado. Há apenas uma variável com o mesmo nome recebendo valores, mas isso não irá refletir no HTML.

Para modificar o HTML, você precisa buscar o elemento do DOM com algo como `getElementById`, e então alterar a propriedade desejada, no caso, o HTML interno.

```js
function alteraJogador()
{
  const jogador = document.getElementById('jogador');
  
  if (jogador.innerHTML == 1)
  {          
     jogador.innerHTML = 2;
  }
  else
  {         
      jogador.innerHTML = 1;
  }
}

// chama a função alteraJogador a cada segundo
setInterval(alteraJogador, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="info_jogador">Jogador: <span id="jogador">1</span></span>
```

Comment: @user14028 obrigado pela ajuda, já consegui resolver o problema.